# Assign value to an array of wires

Tags: verilog

How can I assign whole values of an array of regs to an array of wires in Verilog?
Like this:

```
[5:0]tag_in=tag_in_reg;
```

(`tag_in_reg` is an array of regs and `tag_in` is an array of wires)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Verilog `assign statement`, that will help you to assign values to an array of wires.

```
 module test(output [5:0] tag_in_reg);
  reg [5:0] tag_in;
  assign tag_in_reg=tag_in;
endmodule
```

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile: `reg variables cannot be inputs`.

Comment: [I don't think so](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Bk3), but it seems that some IDEs accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a simple `assign` construct:

```
assign tag_in = tag_in_reg;
```